# Magento Search returns an empty Catalog Element, no "No Products Found" Message

Tags: magento-1.9, search, catalogsearch

One day the **Magento search** was working, and then this morning it appears to have stopped entirely.

**For troubleshooting, I have already:**

- Cleared the cache via Magento Admin Panel
- Deleted the /var/cache/ folder contents
- Switched the Catalog search to Both (LIKE & FullText)
- Re-Indexed everything Multiple Times
- Changed the "default" category from "Default Category: 0 Products" to "Browse Books: All Products"

**Currently, no results show**, and echos and prints within

```
app/design/frontend/progressive/default/template/catalog/product/list.phtml
```

&&

```
app/design/frontend/progressive/default/template/catalog/product/list/toolbar.phtml
```

Do not display at all. I have no idea why the search is failing, possibly due to an improperly defined STORE ID on the Product level?

Thanks in advance.